# Could not apply template when creating new Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I run `rails _4.1.6_ new lala -m app_template.rb -T`

And got `The template [/test_website/app_template.rb] could not be loaded. Error: cannot load such file -- crack/xml`

### The detail output

```
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
       apply  /test_website/app_template.rb
The template [/test_website/app_template.rb] could not be loaded. Error: cannot load such file -- crack/xml
```

### Here my gem list

```
actionmailer (4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.1, 3.2.13)
actionpack (4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.1, 3.2.13)
actionview (4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.1)
active_utils (2.2.3)
activemerchant (1.44.1)
activemodel (4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.1, 3.2.13)
activerecord (4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.1, 3.2.13)
activerecord-postgresql-adapter (0.0.1)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.1, 3.2.13)
acts-as-taggable-on (3.4.1)
analytics-ruby (2.0.10, 2.0.8, 2.0.7, 2.0.5)
ancestry (2.1.0)
ap (0.1.1)
arbre (1.0.2)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214, 3.0.3, 3.0.2)
awesome_print (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
bcrypt (3.1.7)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5, 3.1.1)
better_errors (2.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.3.0.2, 1.1.1.7)
bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails (0.0.11)
bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1, 2.3.2.2, 2.3.2.1)
bourbon (3.2.3)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.4)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.7.5, 1.7.3)
byebug (3.5.1, 2.7.0)
cancan (1.6.10)
cancancan (1.9.2)
carrierwave (0.10.0, 0.9.0)
celluloid (0.16.0, 0.15.2)
certified (1.0.0)
chartkick (1.3.2)
childprocess (0.5.5)
choice (0.1.6)
chronic (0.10.2)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
ckeditor (4.1.0)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.4)
coderay (1.1.0, 1.0.9)
coffee-rails (4.0.1, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.3.0, 2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.8.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.6.3)
columnize (0.8.9)
compass (1.0.1, 0.12.7)
compass-core (1.0.1)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
compass-rails (2.0.0)
countries (0.9.3)
curb (0.8.6)
currencies (0.4.2)
daemons (1.1.9)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.5)
devise (3.3.0, 3.2.4, 3.0.3)
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.8.1, 0.6.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.5, 1.2.4)
em-websocket (0.5.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
exception_notification (4.0.1)
execjs (2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.0)
faker (1.4.3, 1.3.0, 1.2.0)
faker-isbn (0.0.4)
faraday (0.9.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fattr (2.2.1)
ffi (1.9.5, 1.9.3)
finance (2.0.0)
flt (1.3.1)
font-awesome-rails (4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0)
formatador (0.2.5)
fssm (0.2.10)
god (0.13.4)
google_drive (0.3.9)
guard (2.6.1)
guard-livereload (2.3.1, 2.3.0)
guard-rspec (4.3.1)
haml (4.0.5, 4.0.3)
haml-rails (0.5.3)
has_scope (0.6.0.rc)
hashie (3.3.1, 3.2.0)
highline (1.6.21, 1.6.20)
hike (1.2.3)
hirb (0.7.2, 0.7.1)
hirb-unicode (0.0.5)
hitimes (1.2.2)
hooks (0.4.0)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
httparty (0.13.1)
httpclient (2.5.1)
i18n (0.6.11, 0.6.1)
inherited_resources (1.4.1)
interception (0.5)
io-console (0.4.2)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
jbuilder (2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.1.3, 1.5.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.4)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.0, 4.2.1)
jquery.fileupload-rails (1.10.1)
json (1.8.1, 1.8.0)
jwt (1.0.0)
kaminari (0.16.1)
kgio (2.9.2)
kramdown (1.4.1)
libv8 (3.16.14.7 ruby x86_64-darwin-14, 3.16.14.5, 3.16.14.3)
listen (2.7.11, 2.7.9)
lumberjack (1.0.9)
mail (2.6.1, 2.5.4)
metaclass (0.0.4)
method_source (0.8.2, 0.8.1)
middleman (3.3.5)
middleman-core (3.3.5)
middleman-livereload (3.1.1)
middleman-sprockets (3.3.8)
mime-types (2.4.3, 2.4.2, 2.3, 1.25.1, 1.24)
mini_portile (0.6.0, 0.5.3, 0.5.1)
minitest (5.4.2, 5.4.1, 5.4.0, 4.7.5)
mocha (1.1.0)
money (6.3.0)
mono_logger (1.1.0)
multi_json (1.10.1, 1.7.9)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
nested_form (0.3.2)
net-ldap (0.5.1, 0.2.2)
netrc (0.7.7)
nokogiri (1.6.3.1, 1.6.0)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (1.0.0, 0.9.4)
offsite_payments (2.0.1)
omniauth (1.2.2)
omniauth-facebook (2.0.0, 1.6.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.2.0)
options (2.3.2, 2.3.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0, 0.4.0)
padrino-helpers (0.12.3)
padrino-support (0.12.3)
paperclip (4.2.0)
pdf-core (0.4.0)
pg (0.17.1, 0.17.0, 0.12.0)
piggybak (0.7.5)
piggybak_bundle_discounts (0.1.1)
piggybak_coupons (0.1.2)
piggybak_giftcerts (0.1.0)
piggybak_rails_admin_nestable (0.0.6)
piggybak_taxonomy (0.2.1)
piggybak_variants (0.1.3)
polyamorous (1.1.0)
polyglot (0.3.5, 0.3.3)
pr_geohash (1.0.0)
prawn (1.3.0)
progress_bar (1.0.3, 1.0.0)
pry (0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.12.2)
pry-byebug (2.0.0, 1.3.3)
pry-doc (0.6.0)
pry-nav (0.2.4)
pry-rails (0.3.2)
pry-remote (0.1.8, 0.1.7)
pry-rescue (1.4.1)
pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.1)
psych (2.0.5)
puma (2.9.1)
quiet_assets (1.0.3, 1.0.2)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-livereload (0.3.15)
rack-mini-profiler (0.9.2)
rack-pjax (0.8.0, 0.7.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.4, 1.3.3)
rack-ssl-enforcer (0.2.8)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.1, 3.2.13)
rails-erd (1.1.0)
rails-timeago (2.11.1)
rails_admin (0.6.3, 0.6.2)
railties (4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.1, 3.2.13)
raindrops (0.13.0)
rake (10.3.2, 10.1.1, 10.1.0)
rake-compiler (0.9.3)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rb-readline (0.5.1)
rdoc (4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 3.12.2)
redis (3.0.4)
redis-namespace (1.5.1)
ref (1.0.5)
remotipart (1.2.1)
responders (1.0.0)
resque (1.25.2)
resque-scheduler (2.5.5)
resque-status (0.4.3)
resque_mailer (2.2.6)
rest-client (1.6.8, 1.6.7)
rest_client (1.7.3)
roo (1.13.2)
route_translator (3.2.4)
rsolr (1.0.10, 1.0.9)
rspec (3.1.0, 3.0.0, 2.14.1)
rspec-core (3.1.5, 3.1.2, 3.0.3, 2.14.8, 2.14.5)
rspec-expectations (3.1.2, 3.1.0, 3.0.3, 2.14.5, 2.14.2)
rspec-mocks (3.1.2, 3.1.0, 3.0.3, 2.14.6, 2.14.3)
rspec-rails (3.1.0, 3.0.2)
rspec-support (3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.3)
ruby-graphviz (1.0.9)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.7)
rubyzip (1.1.6, 1.1.0)
rufus-scheduler (2.0.24)
safe_yaml (1.0.3)
sass (3.4.1, 3.3.8, 3.2.19, 3.2.10)
sass-rails (4.0.3, 4.0.2, 3.2.6)
sdoc (0.4.1, 0.4.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.43.0)
sequel (3.20.0)
simple-navigation (3.13.0, 3.11.0)
simple-navigation-bootstrap (1.0.0)
simple_form (3.0.2, 2.1.1, 2.0.1)
sinatra (1.0)
slop (3.6.0, 3.4.5)
spreadsheet (1.0.0, 0.9.7)
spring (1.1.3)
sprockets (2.12.1, 2.11.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-helpers (1.1.0)
sprockets-rails (2.2.0, 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.0.1)
sprockets-sass (1.2.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.9, 1.3.8)
squeel (1.2.1)
sunspot (2.1.1, 2.0.0)
sunspot_rails (2.1.1, 2.0.0)
sunspot_solr (2.1.1, 2.0.0)
taps (0.3.24)
test-unit (2.1.2.0)
therubyracer (0.12.1)
thin (1.5.1)
thor (0.19.1, 0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1)
timers (4.0.1, 4.0.0, 1.1.0)
tinymce-rails (4.1.5, 4.1.4, 4.1.3, 4.0.28, 4.0.2)
treetop (1.4.15)
ttfunk (1.4.0)
turbolinks (2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.2)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 1.2.1, 0.3.39, 0.3.37)
uber (0.0.8)
uglifier (2.5.3, 2.5.0, 2.1.2)
unicode-display_width (0.1.1)
unicorn (4.8.3)
validates_formatting_of (0.8.1)
vegas (0.1.11)
warden (1.2.3)
websocket (1.2.1)
whenever (0.9.3, 0.8.4)
will_paginate (3.0.7, 3.0.5, 3.0.4)
writeexcel (1.0.4)
yard (0.8.7.6)
zip (2.0.2)
```

Comment: Do you have the `crack` gem in your template?

Comment: No, here's my template https://gist.github.com/poc7667/172c64bec3d2a010abdc#file-gemfile_template-rb